# Стандартные средства для ограничения прав на конкретную модель

Tags: django

Здравствуйте!

Интересует, как стандартными средствами джанги ограничить права на модели, т.е. мне нужно, чтобы у авторизованного пользователя могли быть права только на связанные с ним объекты, все остальное разрешено только суперюзеру.

Comment: Что значит "связанные с ним"? Те, которые он создал?

Comment: у пользователя есть доп. поле ссылающееся на объект другой модели, вот только для этого объекта у него должен быть доступ на всевозможные действия.

Comment: Уже достаточно избитый вопрос. В документации он в достаточной степени освещен. Да и здесь ответы были.

http://hashcode.ru/questions/74700/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-django-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=74777#74777

Answer (score 2):

Стандартными средствами не предусмотрено. Нужно или писать самому или использовать сторонние решения.

Comment: В таком случае интересно какие Вы, (если используете) используете сторонние средства, т.к. результатами поиска были RowLevelPermissions, но как я понимаю и уже успел попробовать, они только для административного интерфейса.

Comment: В этом плане не помогу, т.к. ничего стороннего не брал. В моих случаях было достаточно проверки вроде:

    def show_entry(request, entry_id):
        ...
        if request.user == entry.author:
            ...